# Exception [EclipseLink-2004]

Tags: eclipselink

I'm having the following issue since a bunch of weeks. See the pastebin link [here](http://pastebin.com/Vh5WYUGb)

**link was deleted and no more accurate with the question**

here's the Runtime context :

1. GWT 2.4.0
2. Oracle 11g
3. EclipseLink Implementation-Version: 1.1.4.v20100812-r7860 (META-INF)

   ```
   <persistence-unit name="EXPRESSO_resourceLocalUnit"
   transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
   ```

Tt happens only and always at application first time call, at that time the applications loads data from database to fill a Grid. Wether the exception is raised or not, data is loaded correctly.

No transaction is used while loading data (i.e: no tx.begin() is used)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleaes turn logging on to Finest to see what objects are involved, and check if you have any event methods such as postload etc that might result in an exception or perform some operation on the EntityManager. 
If the data is populated fine my guess is that it is because your application is handling the exception from the find call and continuing its processing.  The stack indicates that the problem is occuring in a finally block, so it is difficult to determine if the exception is the result of another exception occuring in the try block.

EclipseLink 1.1.4 is rather old, so you might also want to try EclipseLink 2.3.3 or later just to verify that the underlying cause wasn't already fixed, or that it might give a better exception.

Comment: I updated EclipseLink version to 2.3.2, what happens is that I had real application startup gain but the problem still here.

Comment: I turned logging to FINEST which revealed that the commit happend too late (after reloading data). Services (loading and persisting) are seperate services which means that each one peeks an EntityManager at the begining of it's execution.

I added/updated some persistence.xml attributes
`<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="Oracle-JDBC" /><property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.shared" value="false"/>`

Now it seems working, I have to first put in pre-production to ensure that it's okey.